# How can i move my function to the top center of my page?

Tags: html, css

I am looking to move the js function startTime() to the top center of my page. Would I do this in html or css? Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body onload = "startTime(),toDate()"  >  <!--getName()-->
        <h1>Noteify</h1>
        <a> </a> 
        <p id="date"></p>   
          <div id="txt"></div>
         </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need CSS.
If you're writing your date into a div with id="date", then:

```
#date{
           margin: 0px auto;
           text-align: center;
 }
```

should do.
This is assuming you have no other elements above the div.

But if there are other elements coming before it, then you will have to add a position attribute and specify a distance from the top.

```
#date{
           margin: 0px auto;
           text-align: center;
           position: fixed;
           top: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! Another problem I have is that It wont let me call the function in the header. How can I move it to where it is above <h1>Noteify</h1>?